# How to sum a set of results from a MySQL database and avoid getting duplicates in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have users that can make individual payments for some courses.
I have a table for users, a table for payments, a table for verified Payments (pagosVerificados), a table for courses, and for courses that the users have taken. Each course includes a field for the course's price.

I'm trying to do a database query that shows all the payments of each user. Each payment is attached to a specific course.

Now, the problem is that if I do a list of payments and some users make more than one payment for a single course the course gets repeated on the query.

So how may I use that query to get the total amount of each course and then rest from that each individual payment?

### This is how the database is configured:

```
CREATE TABLE cursos (
    cursoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreCurso char(100) not null,
    cursoPrecio int(10) null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE cursosUsuarios (
    cursosUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE pagos (
    pagoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    pagoMonto int null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE pagosVerificados (
    pagosVerificadosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    pagoID int not null,
    cursoID int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### This is the query:

```
SELECT pagosVerificados.pagoID AS pagoid, pagos.pagoMonto,
                      cursosUsuarios.userID,
                      cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.cursoPrecio
                      FROM pagos JOIN pagosVerificados
                      ON pagos.pagoID = pagosVerificados.pagoID
                      LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios
                      ON pagosVerificados.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID
                      JOIN cursos
                      ON cursosUsuarios.cursoID = cursos.cursoID
                      WHERE cursosUsuarios.userID = 16
```

### This is the result I get:

```
pagoID --- pagoMonto ---- userID -- cursoPrecio -- cursoID - nombreCurso
3 -------- 200 ---------- 16 ------ 5000 --------- 15 ------ alfa
11 ------- 25 ----------- 16 ------ 5000 --------- 15 ------ alfa
12 ------- 50 ----------- 16 ------ 8000 --------- 18 ------ zeta
```

**Now, if I want to use PHP to do this:**

```
Alfa
5000
-200
-25
======
4775
```

**How may I do that?**

Comment: Add 'Sum()' and 'group by' to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to lie, I have no idea what your table names or columns mean but this is my best guess. Use this below as a subquery then join to your other tables to get the course name and total price of the course.

```
select sum(A.pagoMonto), A.userID, B.cursoID
from pagos A inner join pagosVerificados B 
on ON A.pagoID = B.pagoID
Where B.userID = 16
GROUP BY B.cursoID,A.userID
```

Comment: Actually the SUM() and GROUP BY cursoID and userID did the trick (both conditions). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, in your query it's better to put:

```
ORDER BY `cursoID` ASC
```

After, your array must be put in a loop:

```
foreach($myarray as $line){
  if(!$precio$line['cursoID'])) {
    $precio$line['cursoID'] = $line['cursoPrecio'];
    $list[]= $line['cursoID'];
  }
  $precio$line['cursoID'] -= $line['pagoMonto'];
} 
foreach($list as $thing){
  echo 'To pay for Curso '.$thing.': '.$precio$thing.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select data where `nombreCurso` is 'alfa' and group by it.
And also in select do sum of `pagoMonto`.

Then in PHP just retrieve `cursoPrecio` and sum of `pagoMonto` and do calculation.

Full code is below:

```
<?php
// Insert your data for mysql connection
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT pagosVerificados.pagoID AS pagoid, SUM(pagos.pagoMonto) AS pmSum, cursosUsuarios.userID, cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.cursoPrecio 
        FROM pagos 
        JOIN pagosVerificados 
        ON pagos.pagoID = pagosVerificados.pagoID 
        LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios 
        ON pagosVerificados.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID 
        JOIN cursos 
        ON cursosUsuarios.cursoID = cursos.cursoID 
        WHERE cursosUsuarios.userID = 16 
        AND cursos.nombreCurso = 'alfa' 
        GROUP BY cursos.nombreCurso";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["cursoPrecio"].'<br/>';
        echo '-'.$row["pmSum"].'<br/>';
        echo $row["cursoPrecio"] - $row["pmSum"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```