# How to show a list of items NOT IN a certain MySQL table? This query isn't working

Tags: mysql

I have a list of courses (that can be open or closed) and a list of users (that can be enrolled into one or more courses).

I have three tables: usuarios (for users), cursos(for courses) and cursosUsuarios (that links the two to know who's enrolled where).

I want to show a list of available courses where an specific user (ie. UID 18) is NOT enrolled.

**I'm trying this query, that's not working:**

```
SELECT cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.cursoFechaInicio, 
       cursos.modalidadCurso, cursos.estadoCurso,
       cursosUsuarios.userID, cursosUsuarios.cursoID
FROM cursos 
    LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios ON cursos.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID
WHERE cursosUsuarios.userID NOT IN (
                                    SELECT cursosUsuarios.userID 
                                    FROM cursosUsuarios
                                   )
AND estadoCurso='abierto'
AND cursosUsuarios.userID = 18
```

**These are my tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE cursos (
    cursoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreCurso char(100) not null,
    cursoFechaInicio char(10) null,
    modalidadCurso char(50) not null,
    estadoCurso char(50) not null,
)

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
)

CREATE TABLE cursosUsuarios (
    cursosUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int not null
)
```

Comment: Consider providing INSERTs and a desired result.

Comment: Helpful style tip: the community has discussed using a "tag" format for titles, and has decided [it prefers titles in ordinary, grammatical English](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495). Would you consider using this format for your future titles? (Your [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38648850/472495) was edited to indicate this community decision).

Answer (score 0):

Move that condition from `WHERE` to `JOIN ON` clause like

```
FROM cursos LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios
ON cursos.cursoID = cursosUsuarios.cursoID
AND cursosUsuarios.userID <> 18
WHERE estadoCurso='abierto'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the LEFT JOIN. If you turn it into an INNER JOIN (e.g., just "JOIN"), that should accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will return all courses that are 'abierto', where userID 18 and cursos does not exist in the cursosUsuarios table, using alias's to clean things up a little bit.

```
SELECT c.cursoID, c.nombreCurso, c.cursoFechaInicio, c.modalidadCurso, c.estadoCurso, cu.userID, cu.cursoID
FROM cursos c
LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios cu ON c.cursoID = cu.cursoID AND cu.userID = 18
WHERE cu.cursosUsuariosID is null
AND c.estadoCurso='abierto'
```